# Xquery giving error on arrow on marklogic qconsole

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to do a simple doc insert with the code snippet provided by marklogic.

```
xdmp:document-insert("/test/shipment1.xml", <shiporder orderid="889923">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city value="BangaloreHighway">>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
<var>Special Edition in the industry</var>

    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>,  

map:map() => map:with("collections", ("PRACTICE"))
);
```

And this is the error I am getting at the line collection.

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Gt_, expecting Function30_ or Percent_
Stack Trace
At line 32 column 11:
In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;declare namespace html = ...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>14078695328357470008</database><modules>99880860359119...</options>)

30. </shiporder>,
31.
32. map:map() => map:with("collections", ("PRACTICE"))
33. );
34
```

.

Comment: Runs fine in 9.0-11. You do have an extra `>` in your city tag..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MarkLogic extension syntax` used, `XQuery 3.1` **apply to (=>)** operators are not supported in `1.0-ml` mode (these will work fine MarkLogic 9 onwards); I believe you are using `MarkLogic 8` or older.

Try using:

```
        xdmp:document-insert
        (
            "/test/shipment1.xml"
            , 
            <shiporder orderid="889923">
                <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
                <shipto>
                    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
                    <address>Langgt 23</address>
                    <city value="BangaloreHighway">>4000 Stavanger</city>
                    <country>Norway</country>
                </shipto>
                <item>
                    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                    <note>Special Edition</note>
                    <var>Special Edition in the industry</var>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <price>10.90</price>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <title>Hide your heart</title>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <price>9.90</price>
                </item>
            </shiporder>
            ,  
            xdmp:default-permissions()
            ,
            "PRACTICE"
        );
```

Also, I would suggest you to refer the function signatures for the respective MarkLogic version in MarkLogic docs e.g [docs.marklogic.com/8.0/xdmp:document-insert](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/xdmp:document-insert).

Answer (score 1):

The "arrow operator" `=>` is available only starting in version X of MarkLogic (I do not have the exact version at hand, I believe it is somewhere between 8 and 9.)

You can use it in any XQuery "version" supported by MarkLogic (`3.1` but also `1.0-ml`).  The following two expressions, with and without the arrow operator, produce the exact same result:

```
(: if you use 3.1 instead, you need to declare the namespace prefix "map" :)
xquery version "1.0-ml";

map:new((
  map:entry('foo', 1),
  map:entry('bar', 2)))
,
map:map()
  => map:with('foo', 1)
  => map:with('bar', 2)
```

If you have only one entry, you can even get rid of the `map:new` in the first notation:

```
map:entry('foo', 1)
,
map:map()
  => map:with('foo', 1)
```

As mentioned by others, in your particular example, you can simply pass different parameters.  But now you know about the arrow operator.